# Transfer Files to Amazon S3 when app is closed

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am using [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/how-to-transfer-files-with-transfer-utility.html#native-track-progress-and-completion-of-a-transfer) tutorial for uploading a file to Amazon S3 bucket, however when I close the app, it stops uploading . I thought `TransferService` is handling that case.
Can anyone please tell what should I change in order the upload would not be terminated when user closes the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS SDK for Android - S3 - `TransferUtility` does not cover the use-case where you can upload/download files when the app is closed. The `TransferService` starting from 2.7.0 is limited to listening to network connectivity changes and does not start the transfers from a service. The transfers are submitted to a pool of background threads and are executed until Android gives CPU cycles. Also, `TransferService` gets killed when the app is closed.

Comment: Okay thx,so how can I handle the case when user closes the app? should I use Service or Workmanager?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/how-to-transfer-files-with-transfer-utility.html#native-background-transfers in this link there is section "Executing Long-running Transfers in the Background" and a sample for useing a service.This should work when user closes the app right?

Comment: Hi @KatyColins Even if you wrap with a service the service gets killed when the app is closed since service runs in the main process of the app. I am checking if WorkManager solves your problem, you can check it out in the meantime.

Comment: any work around for  `getApplicationContext().startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TransferService.class));` for `Build.VERSION_CODES.O` ?

Comment: And is it possible to continue uploading the file after user closed the app or it should be handled manually ?

Comment: For Oreo and above, you cannot do `getApplicationContext().startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TransferService.class));` You have to write your own service that works with Oreo. Examples include JobManager/JobScheduler.

Comment: The SDK doesn't support uploading files when the app is closed. You can check WorkManager.

Answer (score 3):

You can move your uploading code to a service rather than activity. Also you can use a job scheduler.

Comment: Thx for the suggestion, but are you sure there is no way to do that by  aws library?

Comment: @KatyColins See my answer above! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can delegate process to SQS will send a message and for another part a cloudwatch scheduling that handle a lambda function (this lambda read SQS messages and process the object for finally upload to s3)

Another things is that you upload your code for more suggestions.

I hope help you.